# URL Params values are returning undefined with useParams hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am a newbie to React. As a practice, I created a small app. In this process, while navigating from component to another I'm passing a parameter. But when I am trying to access this param value in the routed component getting **undefined** as the value.
Why my code is not working with useParams hook and why it's working with useRouteMatch hook?.

Is there anything I missed w.r.t useParams. Please give me suggestions on how to get the param value with useParam hook instead of useRouteMatch.And what's the difference between both?

**Body.js**

```js
if (this.state.load) {
  this.totalPages = this.state.getVal.total_pages;
  this.result = this.state.getVal.results.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <MovieCard
        posterPath={item.poster_path}
        movieTitle={item.title}
        originalTitle={item.original_title}
        movieId={item.id}
        key={item.id}
      />
    );
  });
} else {
  this.result = <LinearProgress color="secondary" />;
}
```

**MovieCard.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import MovieProfile from './movie-profile/MovieProfile';

const MovieCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="column">
      <div className="card">
        <h3>
          <img src={props.posterPath} alt="Avatar" height="200" width="200" />
        </h3>
        <p>Moview Name: {props.movieTitle} </p>
        <p>
          Original Title :<Link to={`/movie-profile/${props.movieId}`}>{props.originalTitle}</Link>
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/movie-profile/:movieId" component={MovieProfile} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default MovieCard;
```

**MovieProfile.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useRouteMatch, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const MovieProfile = () => {
  let { movieId } = useParams();
  console.log(movieId);
  let match = useRouteMatch({
    path: '/movie-profile/:movieId',
    strict: true,
    sensitive: true,
  });
  console.log(match);
  // const {movieId} = useParams();
  // console.log({movieId})
  return (
    <>
      <div>Now showing post {movieId}</div>;<h1>{match.params.movieId}</h1>
    </>
  );
};
export default MovieProfile;
```

Comment: Interpreting the error it should not match the route. What url are you opening?

Comment: @Julian Kleine. The above code will display a list of cards. Each card is having a link. 
 This is the link I am opening in the browser. Eg:http://localhost:3000/movie-profile/24049

Comment: I will help you, but can you quickly reproduce the error in a sandbox. For example using https://codesandbox.io/ and then share the link?

Comment: I placed all of my code. But it gave me a new error and this error only I seen in the sandbox. I am sharing my URL. https://codesandbox.io/s/d2rub. Can u please correct me If I am missing anything?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-cookies-cwf2e I have changed some of the code, two issues, one was that you imported TextField as named import, therefore it couldn't be rendered, and second one was that when the api call is not working, you overwrote the results, then the array couldn't be read anymore, now i return when there is no result returned from api